# Do accelerations add the same way velocities add in non-relativistic mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity

Can you add and subtract constant accelerations?

Comment: I think that the proper title must be : *Do accelerations add the same way velocities add in non-relativistic mechanics?* so to extend later to what happens in relativistic mechanics.

Comment: The title and body are asking different questions.

Comment: This question needs to be edited. title and body are not the same

Comment: @silverrahul I edited it.

Comment: @barrett-barry , this is too short. You have to provide some details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can add velocities and accelerations as well. This is a useful concept in relative motion.

**Relative velocity** $$\vec v_{AB}=\vec v_{AC}+\vec v_{CB}$$

**Relative acceleration** $$\vec a_{AB}=\vec a_{AC}+\vec a_{CB}$$

But you should always have a clear idea about why you add these velocities or accelerations.<sup>[[1]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652007/addition-of-velocities-vs-addition-of-forces)</sup>