# Which component of velocity should we choose?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In the arrangement shown in the figure, the ends P and Q of an inextensible string move downwards with uniform speed u. Pulleys A and B are fixed. What is the speed with which mass m moves upward?

The textbook solution to this question says the mass m moves with u/cosθ. I have a big confusion here.
If the string inclined on the left moves with 'u', similary the string on the right moves with 'u' as well, shouldn't the velocity with which the mass m moves upward be 2ucosθ?  This is because the component of u along that unknown velocity of mass m will be ucosθ.

The book says: vcosθ = u ; hence, v = u/cosθ

I feel ucosθ = v

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these two methods give different answers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648756/why-do-these-two-methods-give-different-answers)

Comment: Another similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594941/305718

Comment: It answers but I am still looking for an easier and precise explanation.

Comment: @Swami What is not "easy and precise" about the other answers?

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times here. The main problem with your reasoning, as already explained, is that the direction of v is constant but the direction of u is not.

Comment: As for the factor of 2; note that if the left side string were removed and the junction above M were constrained to move along a vertical rail, the acceleration would change, but the relation between the two velocities would not.

Comment: @VincentThacker That's a neat explanation. I got it.